# Can I call a method on a button click via an intent?

Tags: android, layout, android-intent, android-activity

I have a private onClickListener class with a switch statement for everybutton

Some buttons, like returning to my main menu, allow me to have an Intent, because the main menu is called in the defining of the class in the onCreate() like so:

```
//return to main menu

case R.id.return_main:
                Intent intent = new Intent(main.this, main.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
```

But how do I create an activity (on a button call) when I want to access a method that is also within the class I am in?

I can't do:

```
case R.id.snap_another:

Intent intentCam = new Intent(main.openCamera(), main.class);
  startActivity(intentCam);
 finish();
```

Basically, I need to be able to kill the last layout the user was shown when he called openCamera() the first time.  Can I finish(); methods in a case or do I have to somehow make this an intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call an intent for running methods from parent class.

simply call that method like this

```
main.this.openCamera();
```

and you can use the `finish()` call also if you want to exit the current activity

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!  What if I had a button on my main menu that showed the previous instance of what happened after openCamera() was called?  IE:  the last state of the layout I displayed to the user, but only be able to display that?

Comment: You don't need the finish in that case, and start the camere via startActivityForResult() and once finished you will get back to the caller activity.

Comment: well I snap a pic, and place the pic on a linearlayout (set as a child) inside a view flipper...can I call that last layout specifically in my main menu?  Or is it killed when I am back to my main screen?